# How can “Pflaster” also mean “place” or “city”?

Tags: meaning, phrase, meaning-in-context

The main definition of das Pflaster is:

> - plaster
> - pavement
> - band-aid

How is it then possible to use it to mean *place* and *city*, such as in

> - ein teures Pflaster – an expensive city/place
> - ein gefährliches Pflaster – a dangerous city/place

How/why does *Pflaster* mean *city* or *place* in this context? Does the word *Pflaster* intrinsically have such a meaning?

Comment: One English idiom that springs to mind is "concrete jungle" for city.

Answer (score 12):

The expression *ein teures/gefährliches/heisses/... Pflaster* comes from former times, when only city roads had cobblestone (*Pflastersteine*) pavements and thus refers to city roads, therefore - the city, or a place in a city.

It should be mentioned this only works in a number of idioms as above:

> Ein historisches Pflaster

to describe a historic city center wouldn't work, or at least sound a bit odd.

Comment: so i'm understanding that "ein teueres Pflaster" means "an expensive pavement-> city/place"

Comment: @QualityPosts Exactly. And "heiss" can be used with "Pflaster" with a connotation of "dangerous"

Answer (score -3):

The word "Pflaster" originated form the word "emplastron" which was a band-aid with salve on it. Because of the covering and protecting characteristics of a band-aid the word was then used for the pavement covering the streets.

Since the 19th century the word is "Pars pro toto", meaning "a part (taken) for the whole".

Comment: Der Strassenbelag soll seinen Namen vom Heftpflaster bekommen haben? Das kann ja wohl nicht sein, denn die Straßen waren schon Jahrhunderte gepflastert, bevor das Heftpflaster erfunden wurde.

Comment: Mir ist nicht klar, wie das die Originalfrage beantwortet.

Comment: Das bedingt aber nicht, dass man den Straßenbelag schon immer "Pflastersteine" nannte. Siehe hierzu folgenden Dudeneintrag und einen Wiktionaryeintrag: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pflastern https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pflaster

Comment: @Robert: Im *pars pro toto* ist ein Hauch einer Antwort versteckt; dieser müsste aber deutlich ausgebaut werden um jemandem zu nutzen, der die Antwort nicht bereits kennt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft selbst dieser Hauch ist schon fragwürdig, da der Begriff ja i.A. nur in wenigen Wendungen (gefährlich oder teuer) benutzt wird.